Errors when using Firebase JS SDK in Expo project
I'm trying to add Firebase to my React Native app that I'm developing using Expo and Expo Go. I"m using the FireBase JS SDK so I can use Expo Go. I'm also using FireStore. I've Followed the Expo documentation on using the SDK and I'm running into issues when I load the app. I'm getting the following Errors:
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'cacheSizeBytes' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

here is the relevant parts of my App.js file
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeFirestore, collection, doc, setDoc, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = { //all are filled in with correct data from FireBase
  apiKey: "**************", 
  authDomain: "**************", 
  projectId: "**************", 
  storageBucket: "**************", 
  messagingSenderId: "**************", 
  appId: "**************", 
  measurementId: "**************" 
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = initializeFirestore(app);

I also have a useEffect to take some demo data and put it in FireStore
  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeDatabase = async () => {
      try {
        const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users');

        for (const user of Demo) {
          const userDocRef = doc(usersCollectionRef, user.id.toString());
          await setDoc(userDocRef, {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
            firstname: user.firstname,
            charactername: user.charactername,
            characterClass: user.characterClass,
            characterLevel: user.characterLevel,
            campaign: user.campaign,
            bio: user.bio,
            uri: user.uri,
            likes: user.likes,
            dislikes: user.dislikes,
            matches: user.matches
          });
  
          const messagesCollectionRef = collection(userDocRef, 'messages');
          for (const matchId of user.matches) {
            const matchDocRef = doc(messagesCollectionRef, matchId.toString());
            const matchMessages = user.messages
              .filter(message => message.matchId === matchId)
              .map(message => ({
                senderId: message.senderId,
                content: message.content,
                timestamp: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(message.timestamp))
              }));

            for (const message of matchMessages) {
              await addDoc(collection(matchDocRef, 'messages'), message);
            }
          }
        }
  
        setIsDatabaseInitialized(true);
        console.log('Database initialized successfully.');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initializing database:', error);
      }
    };
  
    initializeDatabase();
  }, []);

I'm using firebase 10.11.1 and have tried removing the metro file the expo docs says to make, remaking the metro file, and restarting the server.
